# 'Duplicate' in close queue not showing in original question?

Tags: bug, review-queues

I just got to review https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4700909.  I was being told that a Javascript question ([What is alternative to use after jQuery 1.9 removed `.toggle(function, function)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490957/what-is-alternative-to-use-after-jquery-1-9-removed-togglefunction-function)) was a proposed duplicate for a C question, which makes no sense.

When I go to the actual question, there's no evidence of the proposed duplicate — but I didn't get any 'review audit' analysis either.

What gives?  Does anyone else get the same 'proposed duplicate' when they visit the review? Can you see the proposed duplicate in the question?